# MS SQL: Select from a split string and retain the original order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple select from a Split query.

```
SELECT [id] 
FROM [user] WHERE [id] IN (
    SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('8004, 7943, 2658, 6223, 7826', ',')
)
```

The problem is, the select statement on the user table orders the IDs ascending but I would like to keep the original order that the ID's appear in the Split string function.

This is my code for the Split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter CHAR(1))       
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items VARCHAR(8000))       
 AS       
 BEGIN       
 DECLARE @idx INT       
 DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000)       

 SELECT @idx = 1       
     IF len(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN       

 WHILE @idx!= 0       
 BEGIN       
     SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
     IF @idx!=0       
         SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)       
     ELSE       
         SET @slice = @String       

     IF(LEN(@slice)>0)  
         INSERT INTO @temptable(Items) VALUES(@slice)       

     SET @String = RIGHT(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
     IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK       
 END   
 RETURN       
 END
```

So, the result I currenty get is:

```
2658
6223
7826
7943
8004
```

What I need is:

```
8004
7943
2658
6223
7826
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: post code for dbo.Split function please

Comment: nevermind i see the problem :) give me a sec

Comment: Split function code added

Comment: In the temp table you can add second table and put there your @idx or another "identity" variable and then return from the function a values ordered by your id.

Comment: @sdrzymala the problem isn't with the split function, it's that he is pulling the data out from the user table using the "where" clause. So sql pulls it out in a different sequence than he put in since it's using it's own optimization plan to do it

Comment: Reordering is done because id might be the Primary key column in User table. So a clustered index is what leading to default ordering among rows in data returned.

Comment: I know, but we can force this by addint the fake ID and order by this fake ID. This is a backup solution as for me

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat

Comment: The string_split function has been updated with a flag to include an ordinal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the function as:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter CHAR(1))       
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items VARCHAR(8000), rownum int)       
 AS       
 BEGIN       
 DECLARE @idx INT       
 DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000)       

 SELECT @idx = 1       
     IF len(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN       

 WHILE @idx!= 0       
 BEGIN       
     SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
     IF @idx!=0       
         SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)       
     ELSE       
         SET @slice = @String       

     IF(LEN(@slice)>0)  
         INSERT INTO @temptable(Items) VALUES(@slice)       

     SET @String = RIGHT(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
     IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK 

     --Added Rownumber here:
     ;With CTE as
     (
         Select Row_number() over (Order By (select 1)) as rownum
         ,Items
         FROM  @temptable
      )      
     Update T
     set T.rownum = CTE.rownum
     From @temptable T
     JOIN CTE ON T.Items = CTE.Items
 END   
 RETURN       
 END
 Go
```

and then query as:

```
SELECT U.[id] 
FROM [test_user] U
Join (SELECT items,rownum FROM dbo.Split('8004, 7943, 2658, 6223, 7826', ',')) 
as T on T.items = U.id
order by T.rownum asc
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/TEB18515) here.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the additional field ("N" for example) from the dbo.Split routine that will contain the order

```
N   Value
1   8004
2   7943
3   2658
```

Function might look as

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter CHAR(1))       
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (N int, items VARCHAR(8000))       
 AS       
 BEGIN       
 DECLARE @idx INT       
 DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000)
 DECLARE @N int SET @N = 1

 SELECT @idx = 1       
     IF len(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN       

 WHILE @idx!= 0       
 BEGIN       
     SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
     IF @idx!=0       
         SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)       
     ELSE       
         SET @slice = @String       

     IF(LEN(@slice)>0) BEGIN  
         INSERT INTO @temptable(N, Items) VALUES(@N, @slice)       
         SET @N = @N + 1
     END

     SET @String = RIGHT(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
     IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK       
 END   
 RETURN       
 END
 GO
```

Or you might want to replace splitting routine with CTE version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Splitter AS (
      SELECT
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) AS Pos,
        0 AS LastPos,
        1 AS N
      UNION ALL SELECT
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, Pos + 1),
        Pos,
        N + 1
      FROM
        Splitter
      WHERE
        Pos > 0
    )
    SELECT
        N,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN Pos = 0 then 80000 ELSE Pos - LastPos - 1 END))) AS items
    FROM
        Splitter
  )
GO
```

Then replace your query with

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [user]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Split() AS [split] ON ([user].[id] = [split].[items])
ORDER BY
    [split].[N] ASC
```

Changing dbo.Split is better, because will not affect existing code, but give you reusable solution.