# SQL Server: ORDER BY parameters in IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement that is the following:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name 
FROM Properties A 
WHERE A.ID IN (110, 105, 104, 106)
```

When I run this SQL statement, the output is ordered according to the `IN` list by ID automatically and returns

```
   104 West
   105 East
   106 North
   110 South
```

I want to know if it is possible to order by the order the parameters are listed within the IN clause. so it would return

```
 110 South
 105 East
 104 West
 106 North
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to do so.

Comment: Since they appear to be in random order, no -- there is nothing to order.  IN doesn't order.

Comment: so you want to order it in no particular order...cool.

Comment: OP wants it in the same order as the ids appear in the IN clause.

Comment: These are in order as they are added by a user and the order is relevant to the user so they want South showing first, East second, and so on but there could be other unknown values that aren't attached to this particular query so another user could select NE first and then SW and need them to display in that order.

Comment: @JacobDeskin - that's not how I read the question. You specifically stated "*I want to know if it is possible to order by the order the parameters are listed within the IN clause.*"

Comment: How do you know the order the user inputted them in?  Is this captured in a field somewhere?

Comment: how should i have asked the question. i am new to sql i want to order by the values as the appear after the word IN?

Comment: the values are taken from a list box and the user clicks an export button, on click i go through the list box and if the value is checked i take the value and add it to the string. I could loop through these values here but i figured it was better to create one query instead of running the query multiple times for each value selected

Comment: If the values are coming from a list box, then the IN() clause will not necessarily be in the order that the user clicked the items in, so ordering by the order of the IN() clause would be useless to your user.

Comment: my bad it is in an asp:repeater. I have the items listed. they are ordered by the user before export based on a text field that the user can alter. when the text changes the order changes and then the user can export. but the assigned number isn't stored anywhere in sql so i cannot pull this out.

Comment: Can you change the repeater to also pass a value indicating the order? Some solutions will depend on this, while other (likely more expensive) methods do not.

Comment: If you need to use a UDF because you can't pass that information from the page, there are many approaches. I did a performance roundup here: http://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest way in SQL Server is to use a `JOIN` with `VALUES`:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name
FROM Properties p JOIN
     (VALUES (110, 1), (105, 2), (104, 3), (106, 4)) ids(id, ordering)
     ON p.id = a.id
ORDER BY ids.ordering;
```

Comment: ha ha... I never expected this question would trigger so many answers!! but all are interesting

Comment: This will work if the OP can change both the query *and* the application (to pass in the order). The UDF solutions work better if the OP can't change the application to pass in the order.

Answer (score 4):

Sure...

just add an Order clause with a case in it

```
 SELECT A.ID, A.Name 
 FROM Properties A 
 WHERE A.ID IN (110,105,104,106)
 Order By case A.ID 
   when 110 then 0
   when 105 then 1
   when 104 then 2
   when 106 then 3 end
```

Comment: Hard-coding the values won't work - what happens when the next string gets passed in and it's `112,47,108,96`?

Answer (score 4):

With the help of a parsing function which returns the sequence as well

```
SELECT B.Key_PS
     , A.ID
     , A.Name 
FROM Properties A 
Join (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('110,105,104,106',',')) B on A.ID=B.Key_Value
WHERE A.ID IN (110,105,104,106)
Order by Key_PS
```

The UDF if you need

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('hello world. It. is. . raining.today','.')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select Key_Value = ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

The Parser alone would return

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('110,105,104,106',',')

Key_PS  Key_Value
1       110
2       105
3       104
4       106
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could potentially do is:

1. Create a TVF that would split string and keep original order.

This questions seems to have this function already written: [MS SQL: Select from a split string and retain the original order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076598/ms-sql-select-from-a-split-string-and-retain-the-original-order) (*keep in mind that there might be other approaches, not only those, covered in this question, I just gave it as an example to understand what function should do*)

So now if you'd run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Split('110,105,104,106', ',') AS T;
```

It would bring back this table as a result.

```
items rownum
------------
110   1
105   2
104   3
106   4
```

Following that, you could simply query your table, join with this TVF passing your IDs as a parameter:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Name
FROM Properties AS P
INNER JOIN dbo.Split('110,105,104,106', ',') AS T
    ON T.items = P.ID
ORDER BY T.rownum;
```

This should retain order of parameters.

If you need better performance, I'd advice to put records from TVF into hash table, index it and then join with actual table. See query below:

```
SELECT T.items AS ID, T.rownum AS SortOrder
INTO #Temporary
FROM dbo.Split('110,105,104,106', ',') AS T;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Temporary_ID
    ON #Temporary(ID);

SELECT P.ID, P.Name
FROM Properties AS P
INNER JOIN #Temporary AS T
    ON T.ID = P.ID
ORDER BY T.SortOrder;
```

This should work better on larger data sets and equally well on small ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not rely on hard codes values or dynamic sql (to eliminate hard coding values).

I would build a table (maybe temp or variable) with OrderByValue and OrderBySort and insert from the application.

```
OrderByValue OrderBySort
110            1
105            2
104            3
106            4
```

Then I would join on the value and sort by the sort.  The join will be the same as the In clause.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name 
   FROM Properties A 
   JOIN TempTable B On A.ID = B.OrderByValue
   Order By B.OrderBySort
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this problem is prepare a temporary table for IN clause like

```
declare @InTable table (ID int, SortOrder int not null identity(1,1));
```

We can fill this temp table with your data in order you want

```
insert into @InTable values (110), (105), (104), (106);
```

At last we need to modify your question to use this temp table like this

```
select A.ID, A.Name 
from Properties A 
inner join @InTable as Sort on A.ID = Sort.ID
order by Sort.SortOrder
```

On the output you can see this

```
ID  Name
110 South
105 East
104 West
106 North
```

In this solution you don't need to provide order in special way. You just need to insert values in order you want.