# Return SQL query results in order of input into WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Using:** SSMS 2008, t-SQL

**Goal:** Return results of query in the same order that I input them into the WHERE clause

**Example:**

```
select *
from LoanTable
where LoanNumber in (3,2,4,5,1)
```

Yes, the simplified query here runs, but the results are returned in the order 1,2,3,4,5. When instead I would like them to be returned in the order 3,2,4,5,1 (the order of input into the WHERE clause).

**Additional Information:** The reason for this is because I use a VBA loop in Excel to generate coversheets for each loan number typed into a column in an Excel workbook, and the cover sheets need to be generated/printed off in the order that the operator inputs them. This allows the operator to marry them with another corresponding document easily. But if the loan numbers come back from the SQL query in a different order, this marrying process becomes quite difficult when the operator is dealing with hundreds of coversheets generated.

Comment: The order in where Statement has nothing to do with the order in result set

Comment: if you want to order the output, you have to use ORDER BY.

Comment: @Jens Right, I am wondering if there is a way to make the result set emulate the order of the where statement

Comment: @swe I would like to order the output, but not by some column that already exists. I am trying to order it by the input into the where clause. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: ORDER BY parameters in IN statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751123/sql-server-order-by-parameters-in-in-statement)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892406/what-is-the-ms-sql-server-capability-similar-to-the-mysql-field-function

Comment: So the question I have is does the loan number actually have to be in that set? Or is that JUST the order you want them in?

Comment: @kbball The loan number must be in the set AND the resultant ordered in the order of the set

Comment: I will have to play around with the various solutions offered here and report back what works / does not work. As it appears there is no easy solution to ordering by the WHERE set, I believe I'll have to use VBA to dynamically create the SQL query. I appreciate ALL of the responses to this post.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `order by` clause is the only way to ensure result set order, you would have to build an `order by` clause to match your `where` clause, like this:

```
select *
from LoanTable
where LoanNumber in (3,2,4,5,1)
order by case LoanNumber
when 3 then 1
when 2 then 2
when 4 then 3
when 5 then 4
when 1 then 5
else 9999 end
```

If you're building the `where` dynamically, this wouldn't be too bad though, as the logic for `order by` would match at every step.

Answer (score 2):

The construct `(3,2,4,5,1)` is a set. It contains no order and one cannot ask for an ORDER BY based on it. What you need is to pass in a table valued parameter with **two** fields, one for `LoanNumber` and one for desired order (rank). The query by joining the TVP:

```
SELECT ...
FROM LoanTable
JOIN @tvp t ON LoanTable.LoanNumber = t.LoanNumber
ORDER BY t.Order;
```

Read more about [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I would go by creating a `Table` type to hold the LoanNumber's to be selected. Doing so, the query would look more readable.

> ```
> DECLARE @LoanNumberTable TABLE
> (
>   [ID] INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
>   [LoanNumber] INT    
> );
>
> INSERT INTO @LoanNumberTable VALUES (3), (2), (4), (5), (1);
>
> SELECT LoanTable.* 
> FROM LoanTable 
> INNER JOIN @LoanNumberTable AS Temp ON LoanTable.LoanNumber = Temp.LoanNumber
> ORDER BY Temp.ID;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from LoanTable
join (values (3,1), (2,2), (4,3), (5,4), (1,5)) v(Id, Or)
on LoanTable.LoanNumber  = v.ID 
order by v.Or
```

Answer (score -1):

IF you know your order-expression is numeric, you could do somthing like that:

```
select *, abs(sign(LoanNumber-3)) as Ord1, abs(sign(LoanNumber-2)) as Ord2, abs(sign(LoanNumber-4)) as Ord3...
from LoanTable
where LoanNumber in (3,2,4,5,1)
ORDER BY Ord1, Ord2, Ord3
```

By that, you build a difference per Input, get 1 or 0 if it meets your ordercriteria, and order by that.

This kind of thing is maybe only to be used with a small resultset...