# How to order SELECT results based on the IN() list order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some troubles ordering item using MySQL, example

```
$USER_INPUT = '10,4';

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table Where ID IN ($USER_INPUT)";
```

If I use this query, it will order the items EG: 4 and 10, instead of the user input 10 and 4.

Comment: `ID IN(10,4)` is short for `ID = 10 OR ID = 4`. If that is not what you want, can you be more specific? How are 55 and 20 involved in this?

Comment: Thanks, not that not what I mean for example lets say that my users created a playlist and the music IDs are many and different values, so now i want it to list the item based on the users' playlist… $USER_INPUT = '6,18,5,4,17,89,34,67'; so I am trying to make MySQL list the items based on the $USER_INPUT Instead of listing from 4,5,4 etc. Thanks

Comment: You can follow below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751123/sql-server-order-by-parameters-in-in-statement

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Thanks a lot, trying it now

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur it worked thanks

Comment: If you are storing playlists in a database, it would probably be better to have lists per user, so you can also add a `track_order` column. You can then do an ordinary `ORDER BY`.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Thanks, I also I built a class to fight that:  public function string($string){
     global $mysqli;
     $string = strip_tags($string);
     $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
     $string = $mysqli-> real_escape_string($string);
     return trim($string);
     }

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom order by in order by like the below

```
ORDER BY FIELD(column_name,'1,5,6,7,10,43,867')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your query returns in a descending manner try to place an order by clause at the end of the query
`ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: Thanks,  I also try that but the same result even if I use DESC it will list well but as the $USER_INPUT increases, the list will not be correct based on the $USER_INPUT

Comment: let me see your table and query

Comment: Thanks, @Manoj AP, have been able to do it with the help of Stack Overflow users

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
 SELECT A.ID, A.Name 
 FROM Properties A 
 WHERE A.ID IN (110,105,104,106)
 Order By case A.ID 
   when 110 then 0
   when 105 then 1
   when 104 then 2
   when 106 then 3 end
```

and it worked.